# PM2 run nodejs sveltekit app with options

Tags: node.js, pm2, sveltekit

I have an app that i bult with npm run build, with sveltekit, everything works fine, but i have to specify the ORIGIN like it says here https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/tree/master/packages/adapter-node, to make it run otherwise i run in to this problem "Cross-site POST form submissions are forbidden".
I run it like this and it works fine ORIGIN=http://myorigin node out/index.js.
Now i need to register it to PM2 but i find nothing to run it with the origin parameter.
I have also tried to set the ORIGIN keu in the .env file, and installing dotenv, but i still need to run this command: node -r dotenv/config build, with options, and i cant make it start from PM2.
Is there a way to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

i found this and it worked https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name   : "app",
    script : "ORIGIN=http://myorigin node out/index.js"
  }]
}
```